# Assigning double precision to single precision arrays in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, double, precision, fortran90

I have some routines which make use of double precision arrays but 
it seems that for some of my calculations double precision arithmetic
is not required and single precision arithmetic is enough. For that
reason, I need to assign double precision arrays to single precision
ones:

```
real*8  :: A(100,100)
real*4  :: A_aux(100,100)

do i=1,100
      A_aux(i,1:100)=A(i,1:100)
enddo
```

my question is, this procedure is entirely equivalent to the other process?

```
do j=1,100
    do i=1,100
         A_aux(i,j)=real(A(i,j))
    enddo
enddo
```

As you can see in the first case I can use the vector instruction but I cannot
do it in the second case, which can result in a longer execution time.
After I perform the computations in single precision I required to assign 
back the single precision arrays to the double precision ones.

Is this way efficient to deal with double precision -> single precision conversions at all?

Thanks.

Comment: You could just write `A_aux = A` and let the compiler worry about the details. Note the `real*N` notation is generally not recommended, for more details see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/fortran/939/data-types/4390/precision-of-floating-point-numbers#t=20160830125021290313)

Comment: one thing is not clear to me, when doing A_aux=A the array A_aux will be converted to double precision (before assignment it was single precision)?

Comment: No, you have declared `A_aux` to be single precision, its type will not change due to the assignment.

Comment: And to add to those comments, if `x` is default real and `y` double precision (I'm ignoring that `real*8` horror) then `x=y` is treated exactly like `x=real(y)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply consider comparing the values of the different implementation alternatives (including the one that user d_1999 has commented).

The code below initializes matrix `A` with some double precision numbers and then invokes different routines that convert double precision to single precision matrices (`B1`, `B2` and `B3`). Then the values are compared cell by cell between them and if they mismatch it prints the mismatch and stops.

The code has been compiled and run successfully using gfortran 4.8.5 and ifort 16.0.3.

```
    PROGRAM test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: sp = kind(1.0)
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
    real(dp) :: A(100,100)
    real(sp) :: B1(100,100)
    real(sp) :: B2(100,100)
    real(sp) :: B3(100,100)
    integer :: i, j

!   Fill A with some random numbers
    do j = 1, 100
     do i = 1, 100
      A(i,j) = real(i+j)
      A(i,j) = sqrt(A(i,j)/100)
     enddo
    enddo

!   Use the 3 versions and fill B1, B2 and B3
    call CopyV1(A,B1)
    call CopyV2(A,B2)
    call CopyV3(A,B3)

!   Now compare cell by cell
    do j=1,100
     do i=1,100
      if (B1(j,i) .ne. B2(j,i)) then
       write(*,*) "B1 mismatch B2 at position ", j, i
       stop
      else if (B1(j,i) .ne. B3(j,i)) then
       write(*,*) "B1 mismatch B3 at position ", j, i
       stop
      end if
     enddo
    enddo

    END

    SUBROUTINE CopyV1(A,B)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: sp = kind(1.0)
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: A(100,100)
    real(sp), intent(out) :: B(100,100)
    integer :: i

    do i=1,100
     B(i,1:100)=A(i,1:100)
    enddo
    END

    SUBROUTINE CopyV2(A,B)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: sp = kind(1.0)
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: A(100,100)
    real(sp), intent(out) :: B(100,100)
    integer :: i,j

    do j=1,100
     do i=1,100
      B(i,j)=real(A(i,j))
     enddo
    enddo
    END

    SUBROUTINE CopyV3(A,B)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: sp = kind(1.0)
    integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: A(100,100)
    real(sp), intent(out) :: B(100,100)

    B = A
    END
```